# Binding service in fragment cause error

Tags: android, android-fragments, connection, android-service

I have FragmenActivity with ViewPager and 3 pages inside. All of them bind service with data. When I close activity in all fragments in start function is error. There I bind that fragments.

01-29 21:42:39.394    69

```
45-6945/ E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity Activity has leaked ServiceConnection Fragment$1@419ae7c8 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity Activity has leaked ServiceConnection BillFragment$1@419ae7c8 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:974)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:868)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1762)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1751)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:480)
            at Fragment.onStart(Fragment.java:127)
```

code, in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to the service
    getActivity().bindService(new Intent(getActivity(), Service.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to unbind service in `onStop()`. Add another method to you `Fragment` as following.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    getActivity().unbindService(mConnection);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Otherwise hosting activity will leak the service connection.